# Html 5 File system API, I am getting a DOMError "NotSupporteError"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

I am trying to use the HTML5 File System API in chrome 31. Unfortunatelly, I am getting an error after a user grants access to the file system quota.

This is the error :

```
Error DOMError {message: "The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation.", name: "NotSupportedError"}
```

Code I am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title> JavaScript File System </title> 
  <script>
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;


    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
         window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
          }, function(e) {
         console.log('Error', e);
     }); 

    function onInitFS(fs){
      alert("Welcome to Filesystem! It's showtime :)"); // Just to check if everything is OK :)
        // place the functions you will learn bellow here
        }

  function errorHandler(e) {
    var msg = '';
    switch (e.code) {
      case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
        msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
        msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
        msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
        msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
        break;
      default:
        msg = 'Unknown Error';
        break;
    };

    console.log('Error: ' + msg);
  }
   </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The application has been only tested  locally (i.e. just open the html file with Chrome).

I tried also filer.js, but I got the same exactly error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem might be here:

> The application has been only tested locally (i.e. just open the html file with Chrome).

When you're running on the file:/// protocol you don't get the same privileges as with http/s:///

I would try running it through a web server if I were you.

Comment: Okay, I will try it. However, there should be a way to test it locally as I cannot develop a HTML app and deploy for each change I make.

Comment: It is well worth it to take a few minutes and install a local webserver for yourself. There are installers that do more or less everything: Windows (ampps.com) | Mac (mamp.info)

Comment: glad to hear it. Stuff like that can drive you crazy. Invest in a local webserver for your own sanity!